# Group theory, conjugations yield other element?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

If $A = PBP^{-1}$, then I don't understand how $A$ can't necessarily be equal to $B$, after all, we first transform $B$ into some new system, then execute $B$ there and transform back again. So it's like taking one step to the left, one step forward and then one step to the right, so in the end I've taken one step forward, why isn't $A=B$? Where is the sense behind this definition of conjugation?

I don't quite understand the argument that it doesn't have to be commutative, commutative only means that $ab \neq ba$, but I don't make this assumption in my example with the steps and yet I end up at the same point as if I had simply taken a step forward. Is there an example of the steps where you end up somewhere else because of the left and right transformations rather than just leaving them out (or another if there cannot be one for reasons in this case)?

How does the operator know in which direction the translation must go if the coordinate system remains fixed?

1. Starting Point (0, 0)
2. Go "forward" (1, 0) (positive x direction)
3. Turn around y axis 180 degree
4. Go "backward" (negative x direction)

So did I end up at (0, 0) again or at (2, 0)? Did I invert/ changed the x axis with the rotation? Or what does rotation around y axis even mean for an offset (not at origin) object? I just imagine that it turns around at that point, or does it mean that it has to turn around relative to the axis and "wander around" once? so in my example it even ends up at (-2, 0)?

Comment: What if you take one step to the left, then turn 90 degrees, and then take one step to the right? is that still the same as if you had omitted the first and last step?

Comment: Are you asking for examples of elements of a group (or matrices?) that don't commute? Any book on group theory will have many examples.

Comment: @peabrainiac you mean if my perspective is also turning 90 degrees? I have always imagined this from an outer fixed position and there the coordinates would not rotate with the rotation.

Comment: yes, I mean with your perspective turning. also, for an algebraic argument, notice that $ab\neq ba$ is actually equivalent to $a\neq bab^{-1}$, as you can simply multiply by $b^{-1}$ from the right.

Comment: "commutative only means that ab≠ba": not really.

Comment: @peabrainiac so if you make a step to the left, then a 90 degree turn and then a step to the right, then you are no longer where you would be if you had only made the 90 degree turn, that is because you are not somehow watching from a fixed position from above, but that the base vectors (which span your coordinates) rotate with the 90 degree turn and you then end after the right step (now in absolute comparison) diagonally offset. So you have somehow executed something similar (you look at both in the same direction at the end) but you still ended up somewhere else. (1/2)

Comment: @peabrainiac So does this mean that one performs the operations relative to each other but at the end compares them absolutely to be able to say that A is different from B? So in the end you must be able to compare both in a common system, otherwise you could not say that they are (in this case) diagonally offset. (2/2)

Comment: It really depends on what group you're looking at, and a person moving around was maybe not the best example. For an intuitive example of a non-commutative group, maybe think about rotations in 3D space instead (without any moving observer, just the outer frame of reference); if you rotate an object around one axis and then another, you can confirm for yourself that the order in which you do that matters, and that doing the rotations in the order $bab^{-1}$ is also different from just doing $a$.

Comment: Take a Rubik's cube in its initial  position. Rotate first the right side, then the top side. Now rotate back first the right side, then the top side. The Rubik cube is no longer in its initial state.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thanks, I kind of mixed up the operations with transformations of the coordinate system, so every once in a while I would do a rotation around an axis, rotating the entire coordinate system along with it, instead of keeping it fixed and taking something like "go forward" or "go backward" only relative to the object orientation (instead of the coordinate system). For example, if P is a 180° rotation and B is a step forward, then A=PBP^(-1) is a step backward,

Comment: but I sometimes thought that step forward must still be regardless of the rotation in the positive axis direction, instead of considering the relative orientation of the person.

Comment: I like the step example, it is interesting and made me think. The problem with it, that the other commenters implicitly mention, is that the group in question is implicitly commutative. (E.g. you could think of it as addition on $\mathbb{Z}^2$.) So it won't provide you useful intuition / experience building via examples for your question, because as you point out, the distinctness of $a$ and $bab^{-1}$ requires non-commutativity. The answer by Shaun is clear and explicit example of the phenomenon in a non-commutative group (multiplication by non-singular matrices).

Comment: Rotate your body $90^\circ$ to the right. Then rotate $90^\circ$ backwards, i.e. fall on your back. Then rotate $90^\circ$ to the left. Is that the same as if you had fallen on your back to begin with?

Answer (score 4):

The matrices

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}, 
B=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

are conjugate in the group $GL_2(\Bbb R)$. Clearly, they are not equal.

Here

$$
P=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

(and it is its own inverse).

Answer (score 1):

Lets decompose your operations. First you're adding a vector to translate, then rotating, then translating back. So let $c$ be the fixed translation vector and $v$ the variable and $R$ the rotation matrix. The first translation is $v+c$ which will be multiplied by $R$, then you'll subtract $c$. Putting it all together we get $$R(v+c)-c = Rv + Rc - Ic = Rv+(R-I)c$$

I'll let you figure out how this applies to your vectors specifically. Rather than proceeding algebraical I'd rather appeal to rotations in $\mathbb{R}^3$ since they're all linear transformations and we don't have to deal with the complications of translations.

Towards this end establish the usual basis vectors for the $x,y$ and $z$ coordinates. We're consider just the quarter turn rotations in the planes perpendicular to these vectors. In fact, the important part to consider here is actually the axis of rotation since it's stabilized by the rotations. This will make it easier to visualize what's happening. For this example we'll consider $R_x$ to be the quarter turn rotation (with the usual orientation) that stabilizes the $x$-axis and rotates the $y$-$z$ plane. We'll consider the conjugation given by the equation $R_x^{-1}R_yR_x$ as a left action on column vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. So we twiddle the $x$-axis, then the $y$-axis, then untwiddle the $x$ axis.

Now lets see what happens to the vector $(0,1,0)^T$, the positive unit vector on the $y$-axis. First the rotation takes it to $(0,0,1)^T$ since it rotates $y$ to $z$. Then we rotate $x$ to $z$ which means $z$ goes to $-x$ giving us $(-1,0,0)^T$. Finally, we do the rotation $R_x^{-1}$ which stabilizes the $x$ axis, so it stays at $(-1,0,0)$.  Now we can see clearly that $R_x^{-1}R_yR_x(0,1,0)^T=(-1,0,0)^T$ which is not the same.